# DNS over HTTPS (DoH)

Tags: dns, doh

> DNS over HTTPS aims to increase user privacy and security by
> preventing eavesdropping and manipulation of DNS data using the HTTPS
> protocol to encrypt the data between the client and the DoH based DNS
> resolver.
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS)

If a client uses DoH and connects a web site, can ISP see that which site the client visit and has traffic between client and web site?

Comment: The traffic between the client and the web server has nothing to do with DNS...

Comment: Is the ISP hosting the DNS server? It sounds like you need to understand DNS better. Then DoH might make more sense.